# Extracting values from a cell

Tags: excel, character

I have the following problem.  I have cells with values such as this:

```
    y
1 Alert, Alert
2 Unresponsive, Alert
3 
4 Alert
```

I used the following function to try to extract the first word from each cell

```
=IF(Y2="", "Blank",LEFT(Y2,(FIND(",",Y2)-1)))
```

It works BUT I get #value! for cells like y4.  If there is no comma, I just want the whole word.

Any thoughts?  Thanks for your time!

Comment: Todd, I see that you posted a comment that one of the proposed answers solved your problem.  Please be so kind as to select it as an answer so that everyone else can see it has a valid answer from the search page, and also whoever reads this in the future can benefit from knowing the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The following function will extract the first segment of a list that is delimited with a comma and then a space.

```
=LEFT(A1,SEARCH(", ",A1)-1)
```

Where A1 is the cell you want to extract the value from, and the list is delimited with a comma and a space.

If you had this in a cell:

**y1 Alert, Alert 2 Unresponsive, Alert 3 4 Alert**

This function would return **y1 Alert**.

Now to add on your other criteria:  display "Blank" if the cell is empty and return the entire word if there is only one entry.

```
=IF(A1="","Blank",IFERROR(LEFT(A1,SEARCH(", ",A1)-1),A1))
```

You can read more about [IFERROR](http://www.excelfunctions.net/Excel-Iferror.html) as well as [SEARCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SEARCH-SEARCHB-functions-c4e98f07-eee8-4638-9613-26e15ff3b08b?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
=IF(Y2="","Blank", IFERROR(LEFT(Y2,FIND(",",Y2)-1),Y2))
```

Comment: AHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH!  Thanks!!!!!  That worked like a charm.  I never thought of using iferror.